How to ingest large data from pgVector database and perform similarity search?
I have millions of records in pgVector db as id, content, metadata and embedding.
How do I add all the embedded data from the database into the vector store and perform similarity search?
SearchRequest searchRequest = SearchRequest.query("Which customers are named John?")
    .withTopK(4)
    .withSimilarityThreshold(0.8);

List<Document> results =  vectorStore.doSimilaritySearch(searchRequest);


I don't understand what you want to ingest. pgVector is a vector store.

i think you have to provide filter expression in similarity search method like name==john and this information has to be included in metadata.
